# Reverse engineer MS SQL database to ERD

Tags: sql-server, database, reverse-engineering, erd

How can I create an ERD from an existing database in Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

The ERD needs to resemble: [image]

Comment: I need something like this: http://imageshack.com/a/img537/4511/D2ejLT.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do so, would be from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Go to Database -> Database Diagrams -> Right click -> Add new diagram -> Add the desired tables for your ERD.  Given your tables actually have relationships defined between them the relationships will be drawn as well.

It should be noted, this will be a very basic looking ERD, and might not be quite to the standard of what you would expect out of an ERD.

Comment: Yes, but problem is. I need the ERD for school. So I need a ERD according to the rules of the ERD rules

Comment: Well then, you need to define those rules in your question.  There are many different ways to visualize an ERD.  Management studio offers a simple version of an ERD.

Comment: The ERD created from SSMS is "Something like that", if you need "Exactly that" then you're likely going to need to create it yourself, and manually.  You can use tools such as Visio, LucidChart, UMLet, plenty of others.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this discussion](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/free-software-to-reverse-engineer-existing-complex-database-diagrams-in-sql-serv).
Effectively there is no reliable tool to reverse relationship between tables. SQL Power Architect picks up relationship somewhat better than other tools.

Comment: `SQL Power Architect` has Open Source Community version which supports `Compare, Reverse-Engineer, Forward-Engineer Data Models`

Answer (score 0):

With [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69299715/select-only-rows-based-on-double-values-on-2-columns) you can have an overview of the columns that have the same `name` and same `datatype`.

```
WITH ColumnCount AS(
    SELECT s.name AS SchemaName,
           t.name AS TableName,
           c.name AS ColumnName,
           ct.[name] AS DataType,
           c.max_length,
           c.precision,
           c.scale,
           COUNT(c.column_id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.[name], ct.[name], c.max_length, c.precision, c.scale) AS Duplicates
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
         JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
         JOIN sys.types ct ON c.user_type_id = ct.user_type_id)
SELECT *
FROM ColumnCount CC
WHERE CC.Duplicates > 1
ORDER BY CC.ColumnName,
         CC.SchemaName,
         CC.TableName;
```

When you don't have constraint the closest thing to Reverse Engineer is trying to backtrack the development of the database, what the developers where thinking while developing the structure of the database.

- Hopefully the developers have used the same column name.
- Hopefully the developers have used the same datatype (and skipped implicit conversions).

Is a query based on assumptions but it worked for me.

I look forward to create a Power BI dashboard with chord chard on my spare time. I will update when is done.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is **SQLEditor** from https://www.malcolmhardie.com/index.html. However, it runs only on the Macintosh. At this point the developer has no interest in porting this to Windows.

For me, that’s fine, as I do all of my desktop work on Mac. I have successfully developed diagrams from existing databases on a number of DBMSs, including Microsoft SQL Server on the network.

I have tried for a long time to find something on Windows which shows relationships between columns and not just tables.

The only advice I can offer is get a Mac and get this program. Even including the cost of a Mac, it’s worth it rather than hiring someone to do it for you or navigating through a database blind.

Answer (score -2):

The tools listed require a database to be configured with appropriate primary and foreign key constraints.  If you've worked in enterprise you realize this isn't normally the case.

Search for Sql Caddy.  It is a very useful tool for identifying relationships by analyzing sql queries that run against your database and finding the relationships based on joins within those queries rather than key constraints in the database.

Comment: wat?  Every job I've worked at we've used appropriate relationships between our database tables