# SQL Server :: create an ERD from a database without constraints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, reverse-engineering, unique-constraint

I have a database that was given to us without constraints, no PK or FK.

I'm trying to reverse engineer to find out connections between tables. In order to do so my approach is to create a list of all columns with the same name and data type. So I created this query:

```
SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) AS schema_name
    ,tab.name AS table_name
    ,col.name AS column_name
    ,t.name AS data_type
    ,SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
    
FROM sys.tables AS tab
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS col ON tab.object_id = col.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.types AS t ON col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions] ON tab.[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
    AND [Partitions].index_id IN (
        0
        ,1
        )

GROUP BY schema_name(tab.schema_id)
    ,tab.name
    ,col.name
    ,t.name
    
ORDER BY col.name
```

As result I have this:

| schema_name | table_name | column_name | data_type | TotalRowCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H513WEB | ALPRETAR | IDREVI | numeric | 1439 |
| H513WEB | ALPRETAR | IDREVN | numeric | 1439 |
| H513WEB | CPDOENP | IDRLPP | numeric | 4156 |
| H513WEB | ALPRETAR | IDRNG | numeric | 1439 |
| H513WEB | FAAFACP | IDROLDEBCOM | numeric | 100541 |
| H513WEB | FAAFACP_OLD | IDROLDEBCOM | numeric | 1513 |
| H513WEB | CACPTAP | IDROLE | numeric | 22109 |
| H513WEB | CARROLP | IDROLE | numeric | 5 |
| H513WEB | FAENTFP | IDROLE | numeric | 26084 |
| H513WEB | CACPTCP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 48 |
| H513WEB | CACPTRP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 12942 |
| H513WEB | CAIMDCP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 6637 |
| H513WEB | CAIMGIP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 5 |
| H513WEB | CAIMRSP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 40 |
| H513WEB | CAOREXP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 5 |
| H513WEB | CAPLARP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 3 |
| H513WEB | CARERUP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 175 |
| H513WEB | CARUBRP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 312 |

but I only would like to list rows that have the same `column_name` and `data_type` and the result should look like this:

| schema_name | table_name | column_name | data_type | TotalRowCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H513WEB | FAAFACP | IDROLDEBCOM | numeric | 100541 |
| H513WEB | FAAFACP_OLD | IDROLDEBCOM | numeric | 1513 |
| H513WEB | CACPTAP | IDROLE | numeric | 22109 |
| H513WEB | CARROLP | IDROLE | numeric | 5 |
| H513WEB | FAENTFP | IDROLE | numeric | 26084 |
| H513WEB | CACPTCP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 48 |
| H513WEB | CACPTRP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 12942 |
| H513WEB | CAIMDCP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 6637 |
| H513WEB | CAIMGIP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 5 |
| H513WEB | CAIMRSP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 40 |
| H513WEB | CAOREXP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 5 |
| H513WEB | CAPLARP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 3 |
| H513WEB | CARERUP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 175 |
| H513WEB | CARUBRP | IDRUBRIQUE | numeric | 312 |

How to do that?

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I wrote a post about your query and how it helped me find the solution: https://www.jeeja.biz/2021/11/10/how-to-blind-reverse-engineer-sql-server-database-to-erd/ . 
Do you think I can rename my question "Reverse Engineer SQL Server database to ERD"? Because the title it has now is a bit misleading. Thank you

Comment: You can [edit] your own question at any time, unless it's locked. Just make sire you don't do things like invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to identify PK and FK candidates, it's not just the data type that needs to match, but the length, scale and precision too. A `varchar(10)` can't be a foreign key of a `varchar(8)` for example. In actuality the name doesn't need to match at all, but you would end up with a terrible number of false positives without including that.

I've guessed a little at what you want but i think this might be along the right lines. The (estimated) row count, on the other hand, doesn't seem necessary at all, so I've removed that from the query:

```sql
WITH ColumnCount AS(
    SELECT s.name AS SchemaName,
           t.name AS TableName,
           c.name AS ColumnName,
           ct.[name] AS DataType,
           c.max_length,
           c.precision,
           c.scale,
           COUNT(c.column_id) OVER (PARTITION BY c.[name], ct.[name], c.max_length, c.precision, c.scale) AS Duplicates
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
         JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
         JOIN sys.types ct ON c.user_type_id = ct.user_type_id)
SELECT *
FROM ColumnCount CC
WHERE CC.Duplicates > 1
ORDER BY CC.ColumnName,
         CC.SchemaName,
         CC.TableName;
```

Comment: what is the column ´Duplicates´? I don't get it. Thank you

Comment: It's defined in the CTE, @FrancescoMantovani. A `COUNT` partitioned by the column name and data type (which is made of of the name, length, scale, and precision).

Comment: Thank you, I see where is defined but I don't understand why you are counting and partitioning ´c.[name], ct.[name], c.max_length, c.precision, c.scale´. Let' say that one row has 12 as Duplicates and another has 6. What this column is suggesting me?

Comment: Ah, I get it, maybe you mean that there are 12 or 6 columns like that with the same ´c.[name], ct.[name], c.max_length, c.precision, c.scale´?

Comment: Exactly, @FrancescoMantovani .